# What do you say between recruiter talks in an interview?

Tags: verbal-communication

I've had many interviews for recruitment and the problem I have is that I don't really have an idea about what to say when someone explains about their country and about the company and then the position their looking for. Is it inappropriate to just be silent for the whole part of the explanation? Should I say `Yes, I see` or `Yes, I understand` in between?

**How do you handle your interviews?** I want to know how native speakers handle these situations.

Comment: I am voting to close this as primaly opinion based asking "How do you do ...?" Is a question where every answer is equally valid, what is not a good fit for a platform like IPS

Comment: I also don't really understand the scenario here. I think that with a bit of rewording and some extra details, this question could be left open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through a good number of interviews. So this is what I do usually.

---

**If the recruiters talks directly to you**, then you listen. According to what they say, you may nod your head, say some "ah!" or "oh, really?" occasionally, as needed. If some question pops up to your mind related to what they say, it is perfectly fine to draw their attention that you have a question, and then ask the question. In the end, a successful interview is a dialogue, after all. Both parties should ask and answer - just the interests are different.

In one interview, I was told the name of the city where the business was located, and I was not able to understand the name of the city even after the repeated it to me several times, at my request. I ended that part of the discussion by asking the recruiter to send me a short e-mail with that name of the city, so I can process it in my mind. They did. In the end, I got the job and relocated there.

---

**If they happen to be talking between themselves**, then you have nothing else to do, other than watch. That is, until they finish, and move on with the interview.

---

Bottom line: be natural, as if you were in any other discussion. Don't over-do anything.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. What do you actually do when you're on a phone call and recruiter explains about the country and city? Do you say just `ah!` can we use `Yes` for these situations too?

Comment: If the discussion is on the phone, then it is OK to occasionally say some "aha" or "yes", just to let the other person you are still there and listening. I had a boss many years ago, he did that, saying "yes" - but a bit too often, and at that time I did not know why. It was funny, until I understood that there was a reason behind the "yes"-es. And when I asked about the city, it was on the phone ;)

Comment: There is no strict rule about which word to use. You may even use "I understand" - but it tends to be too long :)